# Scheduled task to map a network drive runs, but doesn't map the drive

Tags: batch, scheduled-tasks

I have a task set up to run whenever the computer is logged onto that deletes all network folders and maps a network drive.  Here is what is in the batch file:

```
@echo off
net use * /delete /y
net use b: \\Server\Share /user:DOMAIN\Username password
exit
```

When the computer is restarted or logged off and back on, the task runs fine (according to the scheduled tasks window saying when it ran last) but the mapped drive doesn't show up.  I'll open the command prompt and type "net use" and it simply says "There are no entries in the list".  If I then right click on the task and run it, it works and the mapped drive shows up.

I've checked the log and nothing shows up.  I've tried adding a timer in the batch file so it waits 10 seconds (ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000>nul) thinking that maybe the network wasn't connected, but that didn't work.  What else can I try?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you not use a logon script?

Comment: To be honest, batch files are as fancy as I've ever gone and anything beyond that seems overwhelming.  I wouldn't mind learning more if I knew where to start.  What would you suggest that is relatively easy for a total beginner to programming that would do what I need?  Any other hints would be appreciated too!

Comment: Is this system on a domain or in a workgroup?

Comment: Workgroup.  Someday I would like to have a domain....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just putting the batch file in the computer's Startup folder?  I can't remember the specifics, but I think the Scheduled Tasks runs under a different context than the Desktop (logged-on user).  By putting the batch file in the computer's Startup folder, it will be running under the context of the logged-on user.

Comment: I tried it under all users and under the specific user.  It didn't work either way :-(   Thanks for trying to help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: If the user simply double-clicks the batch file does it map a drive?  There should be no difference between that and running through the Startup folder.

Comment: Yes, if the batch file is double-clicked it maps the drive just fine. If it's put in the startup folder, or ran as a scheduled task, or as a logon script it doesn't work. I just don't understand it. Very frustrating. I tried it again and added the timer though, and that seems to work.  Thanks for the help!  If you have any idea why it won't work earlier during logon I would like to know.

Comment: XP (I'm assuming this is what you're using) starts all services asynchronously.  Or, as MS refers to it, it uses "Fast Logon".  This lets you log on before all network services are started.  See this article - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831998 - for more details and how to disable.